# jQuery to perform ajax request from form upon submission?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

What jQuery would I use to (check and then) send the contents of a simple form to a PHP form  using AJAX?

The form collects an address and the server will send an email and then confirm the success of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, the $.ajax() method is a litte more versatile than the $.post()..

You can dynamically define whether or not you want to use the get or post method...

An example from the website below:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

where `data` can be info from your form and `msg` is the response data from the request :)

To attach to the submit button click event, put the above code within this function:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
  // AJAX CODE HERE
});
```

read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

hope that helps :)

Comment: One last question: How do I attach that as an event handler to when my form was submitted? (Assume a form with an id of "myform".)

Comment: added that above :) also, ensure your form target is either blank or '#'

Comment: @Damien-at-SF, Can't I just use return false at the end of my JS?

Comment: don't understand that one sorry... getting rid of the form target just prevents the browser submitting the form to that location instead of using the jquery click... in theory the jquery click should be used first, but just in case i make my form target '#'

Comment: I'm asking if I can't add `return false` to the end of the AJAX Code to prevent it from returning the click to the form.

Comment: nothing is being returned to the form all that happens in that ajax chunk is a request being sent to some.php and any response data (in your case the success confirmation) is alerted. :) sorry if i have misunderstood again...

Comment: You have, but it's alright. I got it, thank you for your help.

Comment: sorry about that, glad it got sorted and thanks for the answer accept :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.post().  Pretty easy, actually.

Comment: Mind explaining a little more? Code sample or something?

Comment: Damien elaborated nicely.  I thought you just needed the right keyword to look up.